# Kotlin compare two lists - if ids match overwrite it

Tags: kotlin

I have two lists of `Object`. Both objects have an id val. I need to check both lists by the id val, if the id is the same take the object from list B and overwrite it in list A. Is there a simple up to date way to achieve this outcome in kotlin?

Ive been searching through the kotlin docs and other comparing list questions on here but I havent found anything in the docs or on here that matches my usecase

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have implemented a working maybe not *simple up to date* way yourself?

Comment: Ive been searching through the kotlin docs and other comparing list questions on here but I havent found anything in the docs or on here that matches my usecase

Comment: You need to try something and get back to StackOverflow start coding ... just try it once and get back to us with the code...

Comment: The problem is a bit underspecified here. Maybe other structures than lists would be desirable (e.g. maps or sets) and really easy to use for this use case, but it depends on whether you actually need to keep the order or not, and whether your items are data classes with hashcode or not etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about how efficient this is but it works...

**Sample Class**

```
data class SomeClass(val id: Int, val someString: String) {

}
```

---

```
fun transformList(firstList: List<SomeClass>, secondList: List<SomeClass>): List<SomeClass> {
    return firstList.map { firstClass ->
        val tempItem = secondList.firstOrNull { it.id == firstClass.id }
        tempItem ?: firstClass
    }
}
```

basically, the function takes both the lists and compares each item with each other, and returns items from list 2 if the id is the same.

```
fun main() {

    val listOne = listOf<SomeClass>(
        SomeClass(0, "I am 0, from list 1"),
        SomeClass(1, "I am 1, from list 1"),
    )

    val listTwo = listOf<SomeClass>(
        SomeClass(0, "I am 0, from list 2"),
        SomeClass(1, "I am 1, from list 2"),
    )

    println(transformList(listOne, listTwo))

}
```

**Output**

```
 [SomeClass(id=0, someString=I am 0, from list 2), SomeClass(id=1, someString=I am 1, from list 2)]
```

Comment: That function worked perfectly thank you